# Why do Jdbi3 and Heroku Postgres are not working together?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, heroku, jdbi

**Hello guys!**

I have an error while trying to use **Jdbi** with **Postgres** **heroku**. When trying to connect to the database with a PGSimpleDataSource.

Here's the server error log.

```
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909612+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.Handlers.lambda$findFor$0(Handlers.java:58) ~[jdbi3-sqlobject-3.12.0.jar!/:3.12.0]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909613+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:269) ~[na:1.8.0_242-heroku]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909613+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958) ~[na:1.8.0_242-heroku]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909613+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126) ~[na:1.8.0_242-heroku]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909613+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_242-heroku]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909614+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486) ~[na:1.8.0_242-heroku]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909614+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[na:1.8.0_242-heroku]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909614+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152) ~[na:1.8.0_242-heroku]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909615+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_242-heroku]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909615+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:531) ~[na:1.8.0_242-heroku]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909615+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.Handlers.findFor(Handlers.java:59) ~[jdbi3-sqlobject-3.12.0.jar!/:3.12.0]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909615+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.SqlObjectFactory.buildMethodHandlers(SqlObjectFactory.java:162) ~[jdbi3-sqlobject-3.12.0.jar!/:3.12.0]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909616+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.SqlObjectFactory.initDataFor(SqlObjectFactory.java:224) ~[jdbi3-sqlobject-3.12.0.jar!/:3.12.0]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909616+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.jdbi.v3.core.config.JdbiCaches$1.lambda$get$1(JdbiCaches.java:63) ~[jdbi3-core-3.12.0.jar!/:3.0.0-beta2]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909616+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660) ~[na:1.8.0_242-heroku]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909616+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.jdbi.v3.core.config.JdbiCaches$1.get(JdbiCaches.java:63) ~[jdbi3-core-3.12.0.jar!/:3.0.0-beta2]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909616+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.SqlObjectFactory.attach(SqlObjectFactory.java:98) ~[jdbi3-sqlobject-3.12.0.jar!/:3.12.0]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909617+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.jdbi.v3.core.extension.Extensions.lambda$findFor$0(Extensions.java:71) ~[jdbi3-3.0.0-beta2.jar!/:3.0.0-beta2]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909617+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_242-heroku]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909617+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.jdbi.v3.core.extension.Extensions.findFor(Extensions.java:71) ~[jdbi3-3.0.0-beta2.jar!/:3.0.0-beta2]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909617+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.jdbi.v3.core.Jdbi.withExtension(Jdbi.java:461) ~[jdbi3-3.0.0-beta2.jar!/:3.0.0-beta2]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909618+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.jdbi.v3.core.OnDemandExtensions.lambda$create$1(OnDemandExtensions.java:57) ~[jdbi3-3.0.0-beta2.jar!/:3.0.0-beta2]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909618+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59.all(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909618+00:00 app[web.1]: at fil.glp.wesearch.web.controller.UserController.all(UserController.java:27) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909619+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_242-heroku]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909619+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_242-heroku]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909619+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_242-heroku]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909619+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_242-heroku]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909620+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909622+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909624+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909624+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909629+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909629+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909629+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909629+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909630+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909630+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909630+00:00 app[web.1]: at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909630+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909630+00:00 app[web.1]: at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909631+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909631+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909631+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909632+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909632+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909632+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909632+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909633+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909633+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909633+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909634+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909634+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909634+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909634+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909635+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909635+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909636+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909638+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909638+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:97) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909639+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909639+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909639+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909639+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909640+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909640+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909640+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909641+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909641+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909641+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909641+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909641+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909642+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909642+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909642+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909642+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909643+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909643+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909643+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909648+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909649+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909649+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909649+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909649+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909649+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909652+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909652+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:747) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909654+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909655+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909655+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909655+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909655+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909656+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909656+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_242-heroku]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909656+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_242-heroku]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909656+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909656+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_242-heroku]
2020-02-11T14:09:52.909656+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Here's the code that is supposed to connect to the database:

```java
    private static Jdbi getJdbi() {
        if (jdbi == null) {
            String username = System.getenv("SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME");
            String password = System.getenv("SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD");
            String dbUrl = System.getenv("SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL");
            PGSimpleDataSource basicDataSource = new PGSimpleDataSource();
            basicDataSource.setUrl(dbUrl);
            basicDataSource.setUser(username);
            basicDataSource.setPassword(password);
            jdbi = Jdbi.create(basicDataSource);
            jdbi.installPlugin(new SqlObjectPlugin());
        }
        return jdbi;
    }

 public static <T> T buildDao(Class<T> daoClass) {
        return getJdbi().onDemand(daoClass);
    }
```

If I try to do a simple:

```java
    @SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM users")
    List<Users> all();
```

```java
    UsersDao dao = BDDFactory.buildDao(UsersDao.class);
    @GetMapping(value = "/user", produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody
    List<Users> all() throws SQLException {
        return dao.all();
    }
```

I get the error you can see above.

I already tried to create a simple JDBC connection and that works. I think the problem come from Heroku itself and I can't find any information about this particular error on the net.

Comment: there should be more to the error in the logs (it looks like you only posted a chunk of it). can you try to get the root exception?

Comment: @codefinger That's the only thing that I got from ther server. thank you anyway, I found a solution !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out that I was using the wrong jdbi dependency. 
Instead of:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbi3-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jdbi.version}</version>
 </dependency>
```

I was using

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbi3</artifactId>
            <version>${jdbi.version}</version>
 </dependency>
```